# How do I install the LargeFile plugin for gVim?

Tags: vim, plugins, gvim

I want to install and use the famed [LargeFile](http://www.vim.org/scripts/script.php?script_id=1506) plugin to help make opening large files quicker and easier. I've installed other plugins for gVim successfully, by simply placing the '.vim' file in the /plugins folder. But this plugin is a little different, in that it comes as a gzipped '.vba' file. After I unzip it, what do I do next? As I understand it, the same author created *vimballPlugin.vim*, which is supposed to execute it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you open the .vba file in gvim, you should see at the bottom of the screen, probably in red,

```
***vimball*** Source this file to extract it? (:so %)
```

Following those instructions, execute

```
:so %
```

That will install all the components of the LargeFile plugin and update the help tags file.